# Javascript hiding a div under multiple images

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to javascript and am having some trouble. I am trying to create a script that when a small picture is clicked a div slides open and gives the bio of the person in the picture. There are 5 pictures in a row and the text div is at the bottom of each row.

I am trying to make sure that div is closed if the same image is clicked again or an image on the next row, but stays open and switches to the next description with no animation if another image is clicked on the same row.

After looking around here I have come up with this.

The JS.

```
<script>
$(function () {
    var tabContainers = $('div.tabs > div');
    $('div.tabs ul.tabNavigation a').click(function () {
        tabContainers.hide().filter(this.hash).slideToggle("slow");
        tabContainers.hide().filter(this.hash).show();


        $('div.tabs ul.tabNavigation a').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');

        return false;
    }).filter(':first').click();
});
</script>
```

The CSS.

```
<style type="text/css">
UL.tabNavigation {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
UL.tabNavigation LI {
    display: inline;
}
UL.tabNavigation LI A {
    border-left: 35px solid transparent;
    border-right: 35px solid transparent;
}
A.selected {
    border-left: 35px solid transparent;
    border-right: 35px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 35px solid gray;
}
UL.tabNavigation LI A:focus {
    outline: 0;
}
div.tabs > div {
    padding: 5px;
    margin-top: 3px;
    border: 0 px solid #333;
}
div.tabs > div h2 {
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

The HTML.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="tabs">
    <ul class="tabNavigation">
      <li><a href="#alex"><img id="flip" src="{% static 'img/alex-headshot-stone.png' %}" alt="Photo of Alex Chamberlain" class="img-team img-thumbnail"/></a></li>
      <li><a href="#ed"><img id="flip" src="{% static 'img/ed_snajder.jpg' %}" alt="Photo of Ed Snajder" class="img-team img-thumbnail"/></a></li>
      <li><a href="#nicole"><img id="flip" src="{% static 'img/nicole-phelps.jpg' %}" alt="Photo of Nicole Phelps" class="img-team img-thumbnail"/></a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="alex">
      <h3>Alex Chamberlain<span id=":14h" tabindex="-1"></span></h3>
      <p><b>Puppet Labs</b><br>
        Software Quality Assurance Engineer</p>
      <ul>
        <li>Linked-in: <a href="http://www.linkedin.com/pub/alex-chamberlain/35/9a/911">Alex Chamberlain</a></li>
      </ul>
      <br />
      <p>Alex Chamberlain has been involved in the process of software development in various capacities for almost twenty years, with a special interest in solving real-world problems by applying a thoughtful, user-centered approach to software design.  He has worked as a software engineer, business systems analyst, software tester, and college teacher of computer programming.  In his current position at Puppet Labs he is involved in all phases of testing Puppet Enterprise, an automated system-administration and configuration management tool, from high-level product-requirements analysis through hands-on manual testing.</p>
      <p> Currently he is focused on development of automated web application testing tools.  When not staring at a screen, he enjoys playing the guitar loudly and badly, cooking, taking care of his two elderly cats, and tinkering with vintage Japanese motorcycles.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="ed">
      <h3>Ed Snajder<span id=":14h2" tabindex="-1"></span></h3>
      <p><b>Jive Software</b><br>
        Staff DB Engineer</p>
      <ul>
        <li>Linked-in: <a href="http://www.linkedin.com/in/edinor">Ed Snajder</a></li>
        <li>O'Reilly Webcasts: <a href="http://www.oreilly.com/pub/au/5704">Ed Snajder</a></li>
      </ul>
      <p>Ed is the Database Administrator at Jive Software. He has been administering databases and analyzing data and  for over 10 years, and today finds himself working with PostgreSQL, MySQL, SQL Server and Oracle relational database engines, as well as HBase, Pig and other distributed technologies. He works on query and data structure design, performance optimization, systems configuration and troubleshooting for both internal and on-premises systems. </p>
      <p>When not having fun with databases, Ed is an aspiring hacker, with a self-built 3D printer, a couple of Raspberry Pis, and several mostly finished Arduino projects. An avid Portland tech community supporter, Ed has spoken at and participated in the PostgreSQL User Group, OSCON, Portland Code Camp, SQL Saturday and the Oregon SQL Developers' Group.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="nicole">
      <h3>Nicole Phelps<span id=":14h3" tabindex="-1"></span></h3>
      <p><b>Mash LLC</b><br>
        Software Developer</p>
      <ul>
        <li>Linked-in: <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/pub/nicole-phelps/46/79a/927">Nicole Phelps</a></li>
      </ul>
      <br />
      <p>Nicole is a software developer at Mash LLC in Portland, working on a project for Google. She wrote her first program as a sophomore at Oregon State University and, ever since, has become immersed in software development and entrepreneurship. While currently finishing her OSU degree in Computer Science with a focus on HCI, Nicole is starting the OSU App Challenge, a competition aimed at helping other students develop their technical skills and creativity. </p>
      <p>She has done mobile application development for OSU, Maps Credit Union, BuyBott, and Bioniq Health. Some development tools she enjoys using the most are Native iOS, Ruby on Rails, and Titanium development. When not on the computer, Nicole is usually playing volleyball or reading sci-fi/fantasy books.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4" style="float:left"> <img src="{% static 'img/kelly.jpg' %}" alt="Photo of Kelly White" class="img-team img-thumbnail"/>
      <h3>Kelly White<span id=":14h" tabindex="-1"></span></h3>
      <p><b>Silvertail Software</b><br>
        President</p>
      <ul>
        <li>Building Apps for Windows Phone: <a href="http://www.winphonedev.me/">Kelly White</a></li>
        <li>Linked-in: <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/kellywhite">Kelly White</a></li>
      </ul>
      <br />
      <p>Kelly White is the President of Silvertail Software, a software consultancy specializing in XAML solutions for the Windows Phone and Windows 8 App Stores. He has over 13 years of industry experience building web applications, and has a passion for startups as a serial entrepreneur. Kelly has served on the organizing boards for the Portland Code Camp, Portland Startup Weekend, and the Oregon Game Project Challenge. He also founded and previously ran the Silverlight and Windows Phone user groups in Portland, Oregon.</p>
      <p> Kelly is a Microsoft MVP in Windows Phone Development, and speaks regularly at user groups, code camps, and other developer-related events throughout the Pacific Northwest on Windows Phone and Windows 8 App Development.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This will match the right text for the image as well as give me the animation but I can't figure out how to start with the text div hidden and not animate when clicking the next image or hide when the image is clicked again.

I would really appreciate it if anyone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: Do you have the HTML code?

Comment: I added the HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since all the images were missing and stuff were on top of other stuff, I **started from scratch** and as per your instructions:

## Fiddle

I put in **2 rows of 5 images** for testing:

Each *image row* has the class `.people`

Each *image* has the class `.person`

Each *bio row* has the class `.bios`

Each *bio* has the class `.bio`

**The code is pretty well commented:**

> $('.person').click(function() {
>
> ```
>    // Get some info
>    var openRow = ($('.bios:visible').index() - 1) / 2;      // Open Row #
>    var openImage = $('.bios:visible .bio:visible').index(); // Open Image #
>    var currentRow = $(this).parent().index() / 2;           // Clicked Row #
>    var currentImage = $(this).index();                      // Clicked Image #
>
>    // Hide all individual bios
>    $('.bio').hide();
>    // Show only the chosen bio
>    $('.bios').eq(currentRow).children().eq(currentImage).show();
>
>    // Hide all bios sets
>    $('.bios').not(':eq(' + currentRow + ')').slideUp();
>    // Show only the chosen bios set
>    $('.bios').eq(currentRow).slideDown();
>
>    // If the same image has been clicked
>    if (openRow == currentRow && openImage == currentImage)
>        $('.bios').eq(currentRow).slideUp();               // Then hide the set
> ```
>
> });

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have learned a lot by looking at this. One question I have is when I load the page all bios are showing until I click one of the pictures.

Comment: I got it to work. Thank you again for this. I really appreciate the effort this took.

Answer (score 1):

I've modified your JS so it'll work. Comments are inline

```
$(function () {
  var tabContainers = $('div.tabs > div');
  $('div.tabs ul.tabNavigation a').click(function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) { // this checks if this is selected, and hide section if it was already selected tabContainers.hide();
      $(this).removeClass('selected');
    }
    else { // this is when it is not selected
      if (tabContainers.is(":visible")) { // if it is visible already, hide others and show current section without animation
        tabContainers.hide().filter(this.hash).show();
      }
      else {
        // it is not visible already, do your cool animation
        tabContainers.hide().filter(this.hash).slideToggle("slow");
        tabContainers.hide().filter(this.hash).show();
      }
      $('div.tabs ul.tabNavigation a').removeClass('selected');
      $(this).addClass('selected');
    }
    return false;
  }); //.filter(':first').click(); // don't click the first one on load

  // hide tab containers on load
  tabContainers.hide();
});
```

I've also posted it on JS Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/8VBfW/